# What is a location-based addressing in a neural Turing machine?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, neural-turing-machine

In the neural Turing machine (NTM), the content-based addressing and location-based addressing is used for memory addressing. Content-based addressing is similar to the attention-based model, weighting each row of memory which shows the importance of each row of memory (or each location of memory). Then for location-based addressing, by using shift kernel, the attention focus is moved left or right or remains unchanged.

What is location-based addressing? Why was location-based addressing used? What is the concept of "for location-based addressing, by using shift kernel, the attention focus is moved left or right or remains unchanged."? 
What is the difference between content-based addressing and location-based addressing?